# How could I stop power going to USB Ports without stopping data transfer on a Mac?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, usb

I have an iPod touch and I am fed up with it top-up charging when it is plugged into Xcode. Is there any way that I could stop the power output through USB without stopping the data flow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nominally an Xcode problem but still a better fit for superuser.

Comment: You could try sacrificing a cable and removing pins 1 and 4 from the USB end; these are the power connections. See [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus)

Comment: Is this a programming question? You could perhaps do something via the USB user client, but short of writing drivers I doubt you can do what you want. And even that's doubtful. You might try a hacked cable as suggested, although not sure what effect that would have on OS X.

Comment: No Not an Xcode problem. It has nothing to do with Xcode. it's just that my iPod is plugged in and it is always getting too much charge.

Comment: Sorry, but how can it get "too much charge"?

Comment: It can get too much charge if it is constantly on charge all the time.